# Why Ubuntu 16.04 does NOT show anything?

Tags: 16.04, android

I got a Samsung Galaxy S8+ and trying to connect to my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop via USB. I was able to see entire folders when I connect my old Galaxy S4 to Ubuntu 16.04, but Files shows empty folder when I connect to Galaxy S8+ as you see the image I attached below.

[image]

Comment: Is your phone locked? Is  charging mode instead  of media transfer mode (MTP) active in your phone?

Comment: Are you using a secondhand cable or an official file/charging cable that shipped with the phone? Do you have [developer mode enabled](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42)? If so, is media transfer allowed? Is your phone asking whether to trust the computer or not?

Comment: Maybe some issue about  MTP connection from the smartphone. Look at [this page](https://www.instohub.com/tech/galaxy-s8-and-galaxy-s8-plus-mtp-problems-solved/)